# Why can't I access protected members of base class in derived instances using protected/private inheritance?

Tags: c++, inheritance, protected

I thought that protected members of a Base class can be accessed by instances of the Derived class (or any classes that derive from the Derived class, given that they inherit from the latter publicly).

But I get an error when attempting to do just that in the following listings. So what am I missing?

```
class Base{
private:
  virtual void f(){cout << "f of Base" << endl;}

public:
  virtual ~Base(){}
  virtual void g(){this->f();}
  virtual void h(){cout << "h of Base "; this->f();}
};

class Derived: protected Base{
public:
  virtual ~Derived(){}
  virtual void f(){cout << "f of Derived" << endl;}
private:
  virtual void h(){cout << "h of Derived "; this->f();}
};

int main(){
  Base *base = new Base();
  cout << "Base" << endl;
  base->g(); //f of Base
  base->h(); //h of Base f of Base

  Derived *derived = new Derived();
  cout << "Derived" << endl;
  derived->f(); //f of Derived
  derived->g(); //this doesn't compile and I get the error "void Base::g() is inaccessible within this context". Why?
  derived->h(); //this doesn't compile given that h is private in Derived

  delete base;
  delete derived;
  return EXIT_SUCCESS;
}
```

Comment: Why are you using virtual inheritance here?

Comment: related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/860339/difference-between-private-public-and-protected-inheritance

Comment: syntax error, didn't mean to include virtual in the inheritance clause. I'll fix it

Comment: derived->h() , you cannot access private members outside class ; in derived class the member function is declared private .

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since `Derived` inherits from `Base` `protected`ly, all public members of `Base` are `protected` in `Derived`. This means, outside of `Derived` (e.g. in `main`), those members' name are not visible.

> #### [`[class.access.base]/1`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#base-1.sentence-2)
>
> [...] If a class is declared to be a base class for another class using the `protected` access specifier, the public and protected members of the base class are accessible as protected members of the derived class. [...]
>
> #### [`[class.access]/1.2`](http://eel.is/c++draft/class.access#1)
>
> A member of a class can be
>
> (1.2) protected; that is, its name can be used only by members and friends of the class in which it is declared, by classes derived from that class, and by their friends (see [class.protected]).

Answer (score 3):

> derived->g();

can be accessed by changing inheritance to public.

> derived->h();

can be accessed by changing access specifier inside derived class from private to public(still keeping inheritance as protected,since derived class pointer points to its member function)

Answer (score 1):

When you declare `protected` inheritance of `Base` by `Derived` as follows

```
class Derived: protected Base
```

You are basically making any public methods of the `Base` class `protected` members of the derived class.  If you instead declare the inheritance as public via

```
class Derived: public Base
```

you will find you will be able to access `derived->g()` just fine.

Comment: Yes already tried it and it worked out well, I just forgot the fact that I was actually calling g() in the main function hence the error. Thanks anyway!

Comment: Happy to help ;)